# I would to make all the columns start from 1 in python by scaling them (except date column)

Tags: python, database, dataframe, scale

I created a function to scale all the columns to make them start from 1. However, only one column is transformed.

```
x = {"calories": \[420, 380, 390, 200, 890\], "duration": \[50, 40, 45, 76, 65\], "age": \[10, 80, 45, 56, 65\]}

l = x
```

1. I created a data frame

   ```
   l = pd.DataFrame(l)
   ```
2. changed data to percentage and changed missing values to 0.

   ```
   l = l.iloc\[:, 1:\].pct_change() \* 100
   l
   l.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace = True)
   l.insert(0, 'date', x\['date'\])
   ```
3. function to make all the first rows of each column 1

   ```
   def price(l):
   scaled_prices = l.copy()
   for i in l.columns\[1:\]:
   scaled_prices\[i\] = l\[i\]/l\[i\]\[0\]
   return scaled_prices

   price(x)
   ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you help me to make all the columns start from 1?